# App Opening to Blank Black Screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am making an app that embeds a navigationcontroller into a tabbarcontroller. Now when I open the app I am getting just a blank black screen.

Here is my code

```
PDCFirstViewController *viewController1 = [[PDCFirstViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"PDCFirstViewController" bundle:nil];

PDCSecondViewController *viewController2 = [[PDCSecondViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"PDCSecondViewController" bundle:nil];

ViewController *viewController3 = [[ViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray  
arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2,navigationcontroller, nil];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Do I need to add something or do something different to make the app display? Any assistance would be great! Thank you!

Comment: self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: You should be getting a warning in launch that is a hint to the solution.

Comment: You did not set the tabBarController as your window's root view controller. You must have get a warning on the debug console telling that windows are expected having a root view controller set. Why do you hide the information from us that you get on the debug console? That is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `rootviewcontroller`

Add this

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

That should do it

Comment: Needs to be self.tabBarController, there is no ivar in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```